# Custom PNG background in my tabs, Android app, (can't understand the logcat)

Tags: java, android

Although now it seems I have a button failing and not the background at the moment, so I'll paste in some of my code.

And don't know why I got this problem, so I started deleting the things in which I tried to get the background from, and now I can't seem to understand what the problem right now is. The app just crashed. And after I have fixed this problem, the main issue is to get the same background within all the tabs.

Please tell me if you want any other part of my code.

```
08-08 20:54:11.798: D/dalvikvm(521): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 41K, 53% free 2550K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 175ms

08-08 20:54:17.309: D/dalvikvm(552): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 42K, 53% free 2550K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 119ms

08-08 20:54:21.169: D/dalvikvm(552): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 6K, 53% free 2568K/5379K, external 7485K/9347K, paused 33ms

08-08 20:54:21.549: D/dalvikvm(552): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 3K, 53% free 2569K/5379K, external 16274K/18322K, paused 27ms

08-08 20:54:21.599: D/dalvikvm(552): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 0K, 53% free 2569K/5379K, external 16274K/18322K, paused 31ms

08-08 20:54:21.719: I/dalvikvm-heap(552): Clamp target GC heap from 25.509MB to 24.000MB

08-08 20:54:21.739: D/dalvikvm(552): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 53% free 2569K/5379K, external 18899K/20947K, paused 45ms

08-08 20:54:22.050: D/dalvikvm(552): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 53% free 2573K/5379K, external 18899K/20947K, paused 32ms

08-08 20:54:22.069: E/dalvikvm-heap(552): 9000000-byte external allocation too large for this process.

08-08 20:54:22.169: I/dalvikvm-heap(552): Clamp target GC heap from 25.512MB to 24.000MB

08-08 20:54:22.169: E/GraphicsJNI(552): VM won't let us allocate 9000000 bytes

08-08 20:54:22.179: D/dalvikvm(552): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 53% free 2573K/5379K, external 18899K/20947K, paused 36ms

08-08 20:54:22.179: D/skia(552): --- decoder->decode returned false

08-08 20:54:22.179: D/AndroidRuntime(552): Shutting down VM

08-08 20:54:22.179: W/dalvikvm(552): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)

08-08 20:54:22.199: E/AndroidRuntime(552): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

**08-08 20:54:22.199: E/AndroidRuntime(552): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{taxi.allians/taxi.allians.Tabs}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class android.widget.Button**

08-08 20:54:22.199: E/AndroidRuntime(552):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)

08-08 20:54:22.199: E/AndroidRuntime(552):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)

08-08 20:54:22.199: E/AndroidRuntime(552):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)

08-08 20:54:22.199: E/AndroidRuntime(552):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)

08-08 20:54:22.199: E/AndroidRuntime(552):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

08-08 20:54:22.199: E/AndroidRuntime(552):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
```

So here's some of my XML code inside my `tabs.xml`:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bRingTaxi"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_y = "50dp"
        android:background= "@drawable/button_custom_callcab"
        android:textSize="40dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The `button_custom_callcab` comes here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/callbutton_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/callbutton_pressed"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/callbutton_un_pressed" />
</selector>
```

Here is the part where I try to get the background. This is within the `tabs.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/carbonfibre"
>
```

So I hope you can help me understandning this logcat. How do I get the background correct?

Comment: How big are your images? It looks like you might be trying to allocate too much memory for them.

Comment: @devnate submit this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Image size is too large. Reduce the size and retry.